# Autocorrelation of a wave file

Tags: python, scipy, cross-correlation, autocorrelation

I'm playing around with audio signal processing.
For that purpose, I'm using a single channel wave file from [here](https://www2.cs.uic.edu/%7Ei101/SoundFiles/).

My first experiment was to look at the auto-correlation of the signal as done by the following code.

```py
from scipy.io import wavfile
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np

sample_rate_a, data_a = wavfile.read('sounds/CantinaBand3.wav')

corr = signal.correlate(data_a, data_a)
lags = signal.correlation_lags(len(data_a), len(data_a))
corr = corr / np.max(corr)

lag = lags[np.argmax(corr)]
print(lag, np.max(corr))
```

Given that it is an auto-correlation, I would have expected to see a peak of 1.0 at lag 0 (since I normalize the correlation matrix).

However, the program outputs a peak of 1.0 at lag -36141.
At lag 0, the correlation is -0.3526826588536898.

Currently, I do not have any explanation for this behavior.
Is there an error in my calculation of the correlation or the lags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read your wav file `data_a` is an `int16` array. The correlation will be calculated using `int16` data type as well, this will cause a lot of overflow. To get a meaningful result you can convert it to a floating point array.

```py
from scipy.io import wavfile
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np

_, data_a = wavfile.read('./CantinaBand3.wav')
data_a = np.float32(data_a)
corr = signal.correlate(data_a, data_a)
lags = signal.correlation_lags(len(data_a), len(data_a))
corr = corr / np.max(corr)

lag = lags[np.argmax(corr)]
print(lag, np.max(corr))
```